# When I want to install packages in R, I get this warning

Tags: r

When I want to install packages in R, I get this

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib:  
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib/PACKAGES'  
Error in install.packages(lib = .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) :  
  argument "pkgs" is missing, with no default
```

I was wondering could anyone assist me on this please?
Thank you!
Regards,
Amir

Comment: Without exact code you tried to run it's going to be difficult to help you....

Comment: Coudl you report pleae more details? Which packages are you trying installing?

Comment: On R studio you can go to the 'tools' menu then 'install packages'.

Comment: I've just made a mistake to enter into the apposite box my comment. Please just restore the points you removed

Comment: I can reproduce that *warning* and *error* with `install.packages(repos="https://localhost")` (different url, of course), which is clearly incorrect: `pkgs=` is not provided, the sole purpose of the function, and `repos=` is not responding. For your URL, perhaps you have/had a network glitch. For your packages, we can't know without seeing what produced these errors. Please [edit] your question with the requested information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: > chooseCRANmirror()
> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Error in install.packages(lib = .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) : 
  argument "pkgs" is missing, with no default
Actually, I wanted to install airGR package.